# Find duplicate WEBM files

Tags: duplicate, webm

I have a large collection of files in webm format. Some of them are duplicates. They have totally different names, but their content is the same. It is annoying to find them by myself and then delete them. I've searched a little bit for an application that would solve this, and I only found `UltraCompare`, which doesn't find any duplicates when I select directory with webm files.

So my question here would be: Is it actually possible to do this via some application? Or do I have do to it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MS Windows there is program, named Duplicate Cleaner which can find duplicated files based on the hash of the files (md5) or byte-by-byte compare. You can find the software in Microsoft Store

Answer (score 1):

#### I've searched a little bit for an application that would solve this

I use dupeGuru for this - it can find duplicates by looking at file contents, ignoring the file names.

> dupeGuru is a cross-platform (Linux, OS X, Windows) GUI tool to find
>   duplicate files in a system. It’s written mostly in Python 3 and has
>   the peculiarity of using multiple GUI toolkits, all using the same
>   core Python code. On OS X, the UI layer is written in Objective-C and
>   uses Cocoa. On Linux 7 Windows, it’s written in Python and uses Qt5.
>
> dupeGuru is a tool to find duplicate files on your computer. **It can
>   scan either filenames or contents.** The filename scan features a fuzzy
>   matching algorithm that can find duplicate filenames even when they
>   are not exactly the same. dupeGuru runs on Mac OS X and Linux.
>
> dupeGuru is efficient. Find your duplicate files in minutes, thanks to
>   its quick fuzzy matching algorithm. dupeGuru not only finds filenames
>   that are the same, but it also finds similar filenames.

Source [dupeGuru | finds duplicate files](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with dupeGuru in any way, I am just an end user of their software.